# An amazing inequality of the integration of two functions.

Tags: integration, analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $f:[0,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be measurable and $g\in L^1[0,1]$ such that for all $t>0$,
$$
\int_{|f(x)|>t}|g(x)|~\mathrm{d}x\leq \frac{3}{t^2}.
$$
Prove that for $1<p<2$,
$$
\int_0^1 |f(x)|^p|g(x)|~\mathrm{d}x<\infty.
$$

How to prove?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite the integral as follows
$$\int_0^1 |f(x)|^p|g(x)|dx = \int_0^1 \int_0^{|f(x)|} pt^{p-1}|g(x)| dt dx$$
Switching the order of integration we obtain
$$\int_0^\infty \int_{|f(x)|>t} pt^{p-1}|g(x)| dx dt = 
\int_0^\infty pt^{p-1}\int_{|f(x)|>t} |g(x)| dx dt$$
Now note that $\int_{|f(x)|>t} |g(x)| dx \leq \min(\frac{3}{t^2},|g|_{L^1})$
Hence the above integral is bounded by
$$\int_0^\infty pt^{p-1}\min\left(\frac{3}{t^2},|g|_{L^1}\right) dt = 
p\int_0^\infty \min\left(\frac{3}{t^{2-p+1}},t^{p-1}|g|_{L^1}\right) dt$$
Now since $t^{p-1}|g|_{L^1}$ is bounded near $0$ and $2-p+1 > 1$ we have
that the above integral converges which implies the desired result.